# Why do dates change by 1 day?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime, axios, format

I am getting interesting datetime problem. Maybe it's not problem but i couldn't solve it and getting crazy. Maybe i missed something or i couldn't look at it from true way.

I am getting the data from mongo with axios. The data is:

```
someMethods() {
this.data = this.$axios.get('api_address/sampleparams');
console.log(this.data);
}
```

[image: from axios]

And, if i want to show these data on the my template:

```
<template>
   <div>
      {{ data }}
   </div>
</template>
...
```

[image]

The startdate's value where come from axios is "2020-12-27T21:00:00.000Z", it's true. But I mean, why does it show 1 day less in the template and dom?

My location is gmt+3.

Thank you all.

Comment: do you substract the start date from the enddate? I don't see the -1 in your exemple...

Comment: Aa sorry, I mean, why does it show 1 day less?

Comment: It would be much better to replace the console images with the data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this with axios:

```
 axios.get('api_address/sampleparams').then( response => {this.data = response.data});
```

Maybe your this.data was not updated when you console.log() it.